# Verifying exact solution of ODE by Subsitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that the exact solution of $y' = -xy, y(0) = 4$ is $y=4e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

Workings:

$y' = -xy$

$y' = -x4e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

Now I'm not too sure on what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Multiply $-x$ by $y$. Does this equal to $y'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did it:

$$y'=-x\;\overbrace{4e^{-x^2/2}}^{=y}=-xy\;\;\text{and also}\;\;y(0)=4e^0=4$$ so the given function indeed fulfills the ODE with the given initial condition

Comment: Alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You did it already .  Difficult to plug back into ode?

On LHS is $ y^\prime $ On RHS x times what you got. They tally, done.

You just solved for the Gauss distribution curve. ( max = 4 , SD = 1)